# Sound Problem in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: sound, 12.10

I upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 the day before yesterday and am using it till now.The weird thing is that only the startup sound comes when I log in,then comes silence.

I tested both Digital Output (S/PDIF) and the speakers in the sound settings but can hear nothing. I also tried

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to tick and then untick the mute checkbox ? It worked for me...

Comment: Install pavucontrol. It has several options you can try to test this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of the system. Begin with [this](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/), and if it is not solved, I tried [this](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/fix-no-system-sound-and-audio-problem.html) and it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Your first link is down (500 Internal Server Error). This is exactly why we prefer answers to include the details, rather than just a link.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Open a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and start `alsamixer`.

Step 2:
Go to the *Auto-Mute* option and press *down* to disable this option.

(In my notebook (Sony Vaio SVS15127PXB), `alsamixer` needed to be scrolled to the right to show the *Auto-Mute* option.)